# Maintaining session through a Spring MVC transaction layer

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, session, jakarta-ee

I am really new to Spring and J2EE. The current setup is:

- **A REST API server** which exposes data as REST APIs and also provides a user session mechanism via JSESSIONID cookie after successful authentication.
- **A transaction/relay server(Spring MVC with Tomcat as container)** which will consume the API's exposed by the API server(**using RestTemplate**), may or may not do some data manipulation(**using Jackson**) and finally expose the data as REST APIs to be consumed by the Client App.
- **A client App(AngularJs)** which will consume the REST API's exposed by the transaction server.

My question is **how do I maintain the user session using the JSESSIONID cookie provided by the API server in this kind of a setup wherein I have a middle layer(transaction server)**. I have some idea but I am not sure if that would be the right approach. I was thinking of intercepting every incoming request from the client to the transaction layer, extract the JSESIONID and store somewhere in a global context(sorry for using vague terminologies, I am really new to this) before reaching to the @Restcontrollers and then after passing through the controllers and services before calling the actual API server via RestTemplate, adding the JSESSIONID cookie to the header of the every outgoing request.
I need to do this for every request and that too in the **"Spring way"**.
A detailed step by step answer my help a lot as I am really new to all of this.
I hope i made my question clear. Thanks in advance!